# Python - Find a Number in a String List and return String+Number

Tags: python-3.x, list, find, alphanumeric

Need this:

```
a_1 = 10
a_2 = 15
a_3 = 4
a_4 = 25

x = 3

a_(x) = 4
```

I tried this:

```
list = ["a_1", "a_2", "a_3", "a_4"]
x = 3
matching = [s for s in list if (x) in s]
```

TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not int

So:

```
list = ["a_1", "a_2", "a_3", "a_4"]
x = "3"
matching = [s for s in list if (x) in s]
matching = 'a_3'
```

It worked, but is there a better way?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you need/are trying to do... It might be but I can't figure out what you're actually asking/after. Maybe a sentence such as: "I have abc and I want to xyz which will give me foobar"...

Comment: hm, the error says what's wrong, and you saw that you needed to make `x` a string, so why not simply `[s for s in list if str(x) in s]`. Also, **don't** pick variable names that conflict with Python types: `list` is not a good name.

Comment: lol realy Marcus, thx

Answer (score 0):

I really did not know how to ask, all I needed was this:

```
eval("a_" + str(x))
```

thx all

Comment: I do not recommend using `eval()` for this.  The comment by Marcus Muller is the best answer.